# My android device doesn't show up when I do ADB Devices but DOES show up in my Chrome developer tools

Tags: adb, chrome-for-android

Really not sure what's going on because it seems to be detected by chrome when I plug in but ADB doesn't know whats going on.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running, the OS on your computer, what steps you've been performing, whether USB debugging is turned on. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue (what got Chrome browser on Android to do with it?).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got Chrome Remote debugging working, just make sure that Chrome debugging isn't running when doing things with adb on the command line.

I believe that Chrome has its own version of adb-server so that would conflict with the one used by Android Studio/Android SDK tools.

Comment: Thanks this has annoyed me for years. I was randomly un/replugging my device until something worked. What seems to fix it: let ADB connect *first*, then `adb devices` finds it, *then* launch `chrome://inspect`. (Or, just close the Chrome inspector for a minute and let ADB figure it out, re-open Chrome)